# How to create this Grid using just HTML and CSS

Tags: html, css, datagrid

Hello how can i create a grid like this using just HTML and CSS? Thanks for your help.

[image]

Comment: The data you have shown looks tabular. Do you want a grid rather than an HTML table (which might help e.g. those using screen readers to understand the structure better)?

Comment: im not very familiar with either or but i do know they want this to be responsive. They told me to try to make this with html and css

Comment: Well both CSS grid (perhaps with some HTML divs within the grid) and HTML table (with some added CSS) are a combination of CSS and HTML so I'm not sure what your point is here.

Comment: ok that makes sense actually. I think it might be better to use the CSS grid then

Comment: I came to the opposite conclusion! Because this looks like data which has specific headings - so I'd go for a table but if they've specified grid then OK go for that (or give them both - with an explanation about semantics and accessibility) :)

Comment: It's a question of preference and is grid supported on targeted browsers or not

Answer (score 2):

U can !
U need a table tag ...
Then the head
Then body of table
And finally footer
TR tags are rows of a table
Td and th are cells
Only diff is that th makes the text bolder than then the td tag
Then finally style it with css
If u want to create it with grid i will answer u soon
Just change the colors ...

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <head>
<title></title>
</head>
<body>
<style type="text/css">
  table {
    width: 100%;
    border: 3px solid;
    border-collapse: collapse;
  }
  table tr {
    height: 30px;
  }
  table tr td:not(:nth-child(1)),
  table tr th:not(:nth-child(1)) {
    text-align: right;
  }
  table thead tr {
    background: gray;
    /*COLOR FOR HEAD */
  }
  table tbody tr:nth-child(even) {
    background: ghostwhite;
    /*COLOR FOR EVEN ROWS */
  }
  table tbody tr:nth-child(odd) {
    background: lightgray;
    /*COLOR FOR ODD ROWS */
  }
  table tfoot tr {
    background: gray;
    /*COLOR FOR FOOT */
  }
</style>
<table>
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th></th>
      <th>COUNT</th>
      <th>MINUTES</th>
      <th>TOTAL MINUTES</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>Direct Assignment Position</td>
      <td>18</td>
      <td>240.00</td>
      <td>4320.00</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Indirect Assignment Position</td>
      <td>29</td>
      <td>24.00</td>
      <td>696.00</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Establishments</td>
      <td>17</td>
      <td>29.00</td>
      <td>493.00</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>SUBTOTAL</td>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
      <td>5509.00</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Circuit days of travel</td>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
      <td>1.25</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Travel Data</td>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
      <td>600.00</td>
    </tr>
  <tfoot>
    <tr>
      <td>TOTAL</td>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
      <td>6109.00</td>
    </tr>
  </tfoot>
  </tbody>
</table>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: thank you this has helped me so much. i will make adjustments to match more to the mockups. THANK YOU!